# Где заключаются ключевые ошибки данного аякс слайдера?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Появилась идея сделать самодельный аякс слайдер, обработчик работает вроде корректно, что нельзя сказать о браузерной части...
Ключевые ошибки: приходится производить клик более 2 раз, хотя кнопка должна отзываться с первого нажатия. 2 при переходе ко второму изображению, кнопка больше не отправляет запрос,хотя изображения ещё есть.

```
    function sliderpdr(){
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.querySelector('.getPicButton').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  alert();
  var myPictureId = $(this).attr('id');
      var getImgId =  myPictureId.split("-");
      var getPicture = getImgId[getImgId.length - 1];
alert(getPicture);
       fgg(getPicture);
      return false;
});
});
}

function sliderpdrf(){
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.querySelector('.getPicButton').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  alert();
  var myPictureId = $(this).attr('id');
      var getImgId =  myPictureId.split("-");
      var getPicture = getImgId[getImgId.length - 1];
       fgg(getPicture);
      return false;
});
});
}




function fgg(myPicId)
{
    // иконка загрузки
$('#picture').html('<div><img src="loader.gif" /></div>');

var myData = myPicId;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/tlogi/getpicture.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType:'html',
    data:{"idx":idx,"myData":myData},
    success:function(response)
    {
        $('#picture').html(response);
    }
    });
}fgg();

</script>
<div id="picture">
</div>
```

Вот обработчик

```
    <?
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pages/blocks/security.php";
if(!empty($_GET['idx'])){
echo $_GET["myData"];
if(isset($_GET["myData"]) && is_numeric($_GET["myData"]))
{
    $curPicId = $_GET["myData"];
    echo "string";
}else{
    $curPicId ="0";
    echo "sss";
}


$zzpa = R::find('file', ' iduser = :iduser AND type = :type AND private =:private', [':iduser' => $_GET['idx'], ':type' => 'photo', ':private' => '0']);
if(!empty($zzpa)){

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a["date"] == $b["date"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (($a["date"]) < ($b["date"]));
}
$a = $zzpa;
usort($a, "cmp");
//*******фото
$tsss = $a[$curPicId];
$tssr = $a[$curPicId-1];
$ters = $a[$curPicId+1];
$nxt = ($curPicId+1);
$prv = ($curPicId-1);





//******фото
}else{
  echo "Нет фото";
}


if(!empty($ters)){
  $NextLink = '<button onclick="sliderpdr()" id="getPic-'.$nxt.'" title="'.$NxtPic[1].'"
class="getPicButton">Вперед</button>';
}
if(!empty($tssr)){
  $PrvLink = '<button onclick="sliderpdrf()" id="getPic-'.$prv.'" title="'.$PrvPic[1].'"
class="getPicButton">Назад</button';
}
echo '<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="10%">'.$PrvLink.'</td>

            <td width="10%">'.$NextLink.'</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><div class=""> <img  max-width="900px" max-hiegh="700px" src="'.$tsss->path.$tsss->name.'"/></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>';
}else{
  echo "ошибка доступа";
}

?>
```

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил, косо сделал js получения id

кнопка

```
<button onclick="getdetails(this)" id="getPic-2"   class="getPicButton">Вперед</button>
```

js

```
function getdetails(obj) {
        var Us = obj.id;
        var getImgId =  Us.split("-");
        var getPicture = getImgId[getImgId.length - 1];
        fgg(getPicture);
       return false;
    }
```

Более простое решение